# Swift : call view controller in func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview

I want to call another viewcontroller in  `func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType)` but there is error

> Error : UIWebViewExample[18859:1229622] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

I googled and know that I should call view controller in '**ViewDidLoad**'. however I want to pop up view controller of login directly when I touch '**login**' button in `webview`.

Here is my code

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    let surl = request.URL?.absoluteString

    if  surl ==  "http://myurl/m/include/login.php"{
        print("login pressed")


        ////call login view controller
       var dvc = ViewController()
       dvc.openNewViewController()

       return false

    }

    return true
}

public func openNewViewController(){
    var newController = LoginViewController() 
    self.presentViewController(newController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Please do not add the solution to the question. Post a solution in the "Your Answer" box if you want, it's ok to do that, but a question should remain a question.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to stackoverflow so made mistake. I put my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLEVED BY MYSELF] I put this code to webView(). Do not forget to set identifier of "loginViewActivity" in stroyboard. I do not use openNewViewController() anymore.

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("login") as! LoginViewController
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)


        })
```

Comment: Sorry so did you put the dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
inside the func openNewViewController() ? Or did you put it somewhere else? Would you mind posting or sending me your code? I'm trying to do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

////call login view controller
       var dvc = ViewController()
       dvc.openNewViewController()

*Change the above code to the following*

////call login view controller
self.openNewViewController()